# How to add a tooltip to an element in Vaadin Lit Template

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, lit

I'm using the LitRenderer to render various vaadin-icon elements inside a Grid. There is no documentation on how to add a tooltip to components within a Lit Template.

java:

```
grid.addColumn(LitRenderer.<>of("<vaadin-icon icon='my-icon' />"));
```

Comment: Tooltip as in the "vaadin tooltip" or can you just add a `title`
attribute to the icon and be done with it?

Comment: @cfrick An actual vaadin tooltip. The title attribute tooltip is a last resort because they can't be styled to match the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by playing around with the template.

```
LitRenderer.<>of("<vaadin-tooltip slot=\"tooltip\" text=\"${item.tooltip}\"/>")
    .withProperty("tooltip", gf -> {
                    return "my tool tip";
                });
```